# NAN value and computing angle in equatorial plane with great-circle distance

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, computational-geometry, nan

I am developping a small code with which I need to compute the difference of angles in equatorial plane (i.e the difference of longitudes) as a function of the angles difference in a great circle plane (parameterized by a given latitude).

I used the following formula from [this wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) :

```
d(sigma) = arcos (sin(phi1).sin(phi2) + cos(phi1).cos(phi2).cos(d(lambda))
```

The goal is to compute `d(lambda)` difference of angle. In my code, input parameters are :

`radius = 50
phi1 = 0
phi2 = initial latitude describe below
d(sigma) = (distance / theta) where theta is the local angle in great circle plane and distance is the perimeter of this great circle.`

local angle `theta` in great circle plane starts from `0` and is incremented by `0.01 step`.

Knowing `phi1`, `phi2`, `distance` and `theta`, I can express `d(lambda)` as (in Javascript language) :

```
var distance = radius*Math.abs(theta);
var deltaLambda = Math.acos(Math.cos(distance/radius) / Math.cos(angleTheta));
```

where `angleTheta` is the latitude of starting point (identified by `coordTorus` THREE.Vector3) and equal to :

```
var angleTheta = Math.atan(coordTorus.y / Math.sqrt(coordTorus.x * coordTorus.x + coordTorus.z * coordTorus.z));
```

My issue is that for an initial value of `angleTheta` equal to `0`, an initial `theta` value equal to `0`, then the computing of `deltaLambda` is good but not in other cases :

Let's take for example an initial value of `angleTheta = PI/4` and `theta = 0`, then I have an `NAN value` for `deltaLambda` because in the above formula, I get :

```
var deltaLambda = Math.acos(Math.cos(0.5/50) / Math.cos(Math.PI/4));
```

So I get `Math.acos(sqrt(2)) = NAN`

How could I circumvent this issue and find a trick with which the value inside `Math.accos` remains into `[-1,1]` interval ?

I saw on above link there were others formulas for computing great-circle distance but I need to isolate the `d(lambda)` variable with these formulas, I mean a symbolic expression of `d(lambda)` as a function of others parameters.

If someone could give another consistent formula or find a way to avoid `NAN value error`, this would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It impossible that for lat1=0, lat2=45 great circle distance is 1/100 of radius! Minimal possible d is `Sqrt(2)/2 * R`. So you take illegal starting data for calculations.

Another issue - wrong formula to get latitude from Cartesian coordinates. [Right one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates):

```
lat = Arccos(z/R) 
or 
lat = atan(Sqrt(x^2+y^2) / z)
```

Comment: ok, the issue seems to come from the theta starting angle (into plane of the great circle) but I don't know which value to take in this local plane and the corresponding angle in equatorial plane.